# Visual studio VSPackage behavior different after installation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, vspackage

I have developped a Visual studio 2010 VSPackage in C#. It's role is to show an assembly types and methods in a Treeview. It uses reflexion like this :

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(strAssemblyPath);  
foreach (Type a_type in assembly.GetTypes())  
{  
    foreach (MethodInfo mi in a_type.GetMethods())  
    {  
        //code to handle methods here  
    }  
}
```

I have several Assemblies that reference others, all situated in the same folder.

It works fine when I debug the application : the getTypes() and getMethods() don't raise any errors when trying to load types from others assemblies.

When I generate a .vsix installer, (debug or release), and use the plugin afer installing it, the getTypes() and GetMethods() raise errors of type :
'Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies' but the assemblies are in the folder...

Some more informations :

- I use the default settings for my VSPackage solution.
- the command line in debug is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /rootsuffix Exp"
- I try the same action on the exact same assemblies in the exact same folder while debugging and after installation of the package.
- Visual studio is started as Administrator in both cases

Does anyone know why the behavior of the GetTypes() and GetMethods() is different ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't know why the behavior is different, but I was able to limit the impact of the error with correct error handling. The error handling I use is this ;

```
Type[] types = null;
try
{
    types = assembly.GetTypes();
}
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
{
    types = e.Types;
    StringBuilder strErrors = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Exception exError in e.LoaderExceptions)
    {
        //Message errors can appear several times.
        if (!strErrors.ToString().Contains(exError.Message))
        {
             strErrors.Append(exError.Message);
             Exception innerError = exError.InnerException;
             while (innerError != null)
             {
                 strErrors.Append(innerError.Message);
                 innerError = innerError.InnerException;
             }
        }
    }
    //trace the error
}
if (types != null)
{
    foreach (Type a_type in types)
    {
         //handle types in here
    }
}
```

Before, I just catched the exception and didn't handle the types defined in the ReflectionTypeLoadException.Types.